# Markdown notes within tex document chapter

Tags: chapters, markdown

I wish to add blocks of markdown notes within my thesis. However, whenever I use `\begin{markdown}` it automatically starts a new chapter.

For example, this will generate two chapters, with the markdown list at the start of chapter 2:

**main.tex**:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{ociamthesis}
\begin{document}
\chapter{\label{ch:1-intro}Introduction} 

I want this to be in Chapter 1

\begin{markdown}
# I want this to be in Chapter 1 but somehow it starts Chapter 2
- bullet 1
    - bullet 2
    - bullet 3
\end{markdown}

I want this to be in Chapter 1 too
\end{document}
```

**ociamthesis.cls**:

```
\LoadClass[openright,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[hybrid]{markdown}
```

Is there anyway to include markdown code without starting a new chapter? (I'm using Overleaf)

I'm not a regular user of latex. So please let me know if you require more information to answer this question.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please post a complete compilable but minimal example here. In order to know how to best help you, it is always better to know at least a bit about your set up and especially the packages you use  Also, do you want the markdown code to be rendered as LaTeX or just print it as it is (verbatim)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- I never used the [`markdown` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/markdown) before: There may be a better explanation.
- The package seems to be interesting, especially considering the authors (e. g. [Hans Hagen](https://tug.org/interviews/hagen.html) who is the author of [ConTeXt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ConTeXt)).
- You use `##` within markdown which is apparently a 2nd-level heading.
- This is like a `\section` command and therefore you get `1.1 Test`.
- **`-->` The solution is to not use a markdown heading command (like `##`) if you don't want a new heading :).**

***Remark 1:*** I had to run the code using the `-shell-escape` compile option. Otherwise I got a corresponding error message.

***Remark 2:*** The original question used `##` (2nd-level heading) later the code in the question was changed to `#`.

### Your Code (incl. `##`)

```
%% pdflatex -shell-escape %.tex 

\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[hybrid]{markdown} % [hybrid] is not relevant in this example.
\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction} 

I want this to be in Chapter 1

\begin{markdown}
## Test
**bold**
\end{markdown}

I want this to be in Chapter 1 too
\end{document}
```

[image]

### My Code (excl. `##`)

```
%% pdflatex -shell-escape %.tex 

\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[hybrid]{markdown} % [hybrid] is not relevant in this example.
\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction} 

I want this to be in Chapter 1

\begin{markdown}
**bold**
\end{markdown}

I want this to be in Chapter 1 too
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I realised the minimal example i originally fabricated actually puts everything into a single chapter (because i used "##"). I've changed my example back to "#" so everything would make sense to the future reader of this thread.

Comment: @matohak Ok, good. I have noticed that your code and your problem description do not align but I did not mention it because is did not matter,

Answer (score 0):

I'd use this opportunity to present a radically different and somewhat more flexible pipeline. It does not depend on `markdown` package at all. I use `pandoc`, but basically any markdown to TeX converter can be used.

Basically, I write a LaTeX main file, for example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}
\include{content} % !!!!
\end{document}
```

The `content.md` is a markdown file, for example:

```
## Heading

Hello, I am *markdown*, _not_ **markup**!
```

The magic happens in a `Makefile` (yeah, Linux and Mac world, but should work on Windows with corresponding additional software, such as Cygwun):

```
main.pdf : main.tex content.tex Makefile
    latexmk -pdf main

content.tex : content.md Makefile
    pandoc -f markdown+smart+raw_tex --natbib -t latex content.md -o content.tex

clean :
    latexmk -C -pdf main
    rm -f content.tex
```

Now, with a simple `make` command a document is built from Markdown to PDF with LaTeX using all the required LaTeX things from main.tex (such as journal paper formatting or fonts).

Notice, that my Makefile includes a `raw_tex` filter, so you can write in *markdown* file:

````
```{=latex}
\begin{figure}[tb]
FIGURE
\end{figure}
```
````

The marked segment will be passed to LaTeX as is. From experience, `pandoc` detects many LaTeX commands even without it, so `\mycommand{foo}` works even without that filter.

Comment: Thanks for the code. From what I read in the manual of the `markdown` package, the goal of the package is to avoid external tools.